# Where can I find my suggested edits page?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I'm curious about which of my submitted edits get accepted and denied.

Is there a way I can find a page with a complete list of all my edits? Both those that were accepted and those where were rejected?

I am aware of [this](https://askubuntu.com/users/6005/james-gifford?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_revisions) page, but that only shows my accepted ones, not my rejected edits as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry about the belated response.

To view your suggested edits, go to your profile, switch to the Activity tab and then filter by suggestions:

https://askubuntu.com/users/6005/jrg?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: I don't think that was a "feature" at the time I asked this, but thanks! :)